# PHP shows array keys 1 number higher

Tags: php, mysql

I want to get all keys of an array showing on my page.

Right now I have this:

```
$subjectcodes[1] = "Mathematics";
$subjectcodes[2] = "Physics";
$subjectcodes[3] = "Charlie";
$subjectcodes[4] = "Chemistry";
$subjectcodes[5] = "Biology";
$subjectcodes[6] = "English";
$subjectcodes[7] = "Dutch";
$subjectcodes[8] = "German";
$subjectcodes[9] = "Sociology";
$subjectcodes[10] = "Physical Education";
$subjectcodes[11] = "Art";
$subjectcodes[12] = "General Science";
$subjectcodes[13] = "Philosophy";
$subjectcodes[14] = "Management and Organization";
$subjectcodes[15] = "Research and Design";

foreach ($subjectcodes as &$value) {
        $key = key($subjectcodes);
        echo "<option value=" . $key . ">" . $value . "</option>";
}
```

When I go to my page with that code I get:

```
<option value=2>Mathematics</option>
<option value=3>Physics</option>
<option value=4>Charlie</option>
<option value=5>Chemistry</option>
<option value=6>Biology</option>
<option value=7>English</option>
<option value=8>Dutch</option>
<option value=9>German</option>
<option value=10>Sociology</option>
<option value=11>Physical Education</option>
<option value=12>Art</option>
<option value=13>General Science</option>
<option value=14>Philosophy</option>
<option value=15>Management and Organization</option>
<option value=>Research and Design</option></select>
```

As you can see all keys are 1 higher number then supposed. And the last option doesn't even have a key...

Does anyone why this is, and how I can solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: This is a strange way to write a foreach!

Comment: @Yousf Can you also tell why?

Comment: Choosing the foreach loop variable to be reference, and getting the key from inside the loop. The standard way is as @Niloy Shaa said. `foreach($my_array as $key => $value)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```
foreach ($subjectcodes as $key=>$value) {
    //$key = key($subjectcodes);
    echo "<option value=" . $key . ">" . $value . "</option>";
}
```

Comment: I will, but I have to wait 11 minutes

Answer (score 3):

you can use key and value in [foreach()](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php), so change:

```
foreach ($subjectcodes as &$value) {
    $key = key($subjectcodes);
    echo "<option value=" . $key . ">" . $value . "</option>";
}
```

to

```
foreach ($subjectcodes as $key => $value) {
    echo "<option value=" . $key . ">" . $value . "</option>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Foreach iterates over the array, this means that when you use the key method the "current" array element is the next on your foreach cycle. Your code is not well constructed for what you are trying to acomplish.

Use this instead:

```
foreach ($subjectcodes as $key => $value) {
    echo "<option value=" . $key . ">" . $value . "</option>";
}
```

Note: Unless you want to change the value of the array element inside the foreach cycle there is no need to use &$value.

Answer (score 1):

A note to complete the info about using reference as foreach loop variables:

From http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php:

> Reference of a $value and the last array element remain even after
>   the foreach loop. It is recommended to destroy it by unset().

So if you decided to use a reference as a foreach variable, you have unset it after the foreach.

```
foreach ($subjectcodes as &$value)
{
}
unset($value)
```